# How do I return an exception from Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have made an Azure Mobile Service which works fine locally.

I then publish the Azure mobile Service to the cloud and the website shows that it is currently running.

I then make a `GET Request` to my published website and it returns the following:

> Status 500 Internal Server Error 500 Internal Server Error A generic
>   error message, given when no more specific message is suitable
>
> {   "message": "An error has occurred." }

I have tried adding:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
```

To my `Web.Config` in the `Site\wwwroot` directory but this didn't do anything.

So how do I return a more meaningful error from my azure mobile service?

Comment: With the `customErrors` off have you tried making the call using Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)? You can check the raw response then which should give you an indication of the error encountered. You could also try remote debugging http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: @Flexicoder I get the same response from fiddler (previously I was using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/))

Comment: But can't you now look at the raw response? It should give you some more info with customErrors now off

Comment: @Flexicoder if you are interrested I have posted the answer below. `customErrors` doesn't effect `Web API's`

Comment: I'll take a look, but I do get the details when the API goes wrong, but I'll check this out as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So turns out returning errors from a `Web API` is different to returning errors from `Asp.net` or `iis`

From [this link](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/18/custom-errors-and-error-detail-policy-in-asp-net-web-api/) I found the following:

> Today Kurt and I were attempting to debug an Web API service we had
>   deployed to a remote machine. The service was returning 500 errors,
>   and for various reasons, we couldn’t just try to do the requests from
>   that deployed box. We wanted to get the full exception details in the
>   response, but we were just seeing blank 500 errors, with no responses.
>
> We first tried the Web.Config setting for custom errors:
>
> ```
> <customErrors mode="Off" />
> ```
>
> But this didn’t affect anything. Digging a little further, we found
>   that ASP.NET Web API uses a different configuration for error details
>   being passed along. This is for a couple of reasons; first, the custom
>   errors element in the Web.Config is an ASP.NET thing. It’s something
>   that ASP.NET uses to determine if that yellow screen of death with
>   additional detail should be shown to users. However, ASP.NET Web API
>   is designed to be self-hosted, outside of ASP.NET and IIS. While the
>   customErrors element affects requests for ASPX and MVC, it does
>   nothing for Web API.
>
> Instead of relying on a lot of XML configuration, Web API uses a lot
>   of programmatic configuration. This helps self hosting, but for
>   changing policies like error detail, we have to change the code,
>   re-compile and re-deploy. To set the error policy in our application,
>   we need to modify our global Web API configuration:
>
> ```
> GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy 
>     = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
> ```
>
> With this mode, requests from any source will get us full exception
>   detail. It’s likely not something we want in production, but nice that
>   it is available.

So in conclusion to view errors from a `Web API` you want to go to your `Startup` class where you will see a `ConfigureMobileApp` method.

This will include the line:

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
```

and you want to add the following:

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Mobile Service handles all exceptions and raises an HttpResponseException with generic error message, if you want to get the detailed error message yo can do something like this:

```
// POST tables/TodoItem
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
{
  try
  {
    TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(item);
    return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
  }
  catch (HttpResponseException ex)
  {
    string message = ((HttpError)((ObjectContent)ex.Response.Content).Value).First().Value.ToString();
    string[] temp = message.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
      Content = new StringContent(message),
      ReasonPhrase = temp[0]
    };
    throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
  }
}
```

This [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling) point me in the right direction