# Azure mobile sync backend internal error

Tags: synchronization, azure-mobile-services, backend, azure-api-apps

Hope someone can help me, I've been going around and around for sometime now with this problem and I'm hoping its something small I've missed.

I've got a SQL server database on Azure which is linked to the Mobile syncing solution.
I used the quick start and got a backend and mobile app etc for the TODO.  Which added a toDOitem table into my DB.

Now I am trying to create a controller etc to match another table  from the DB, using the ToDO as a template.
When I do a push I get no error, but no data is added, but when I do a pull it comes back with a internal error exception.

The Controller

```
public class InterventionController : TableController<Intervention>
    {
        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            HDTermTypeBETAContext context = new HDTermTypeBETAContext();
            DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Intervention>(context, Request);
        }

    // GET tables/TodoItem
    public IQueryable<Intervention> GetAllIntervention()
    {
        var a = Query();
        return Query();
    }

    // GET tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public SingleResult<Intervention> GetIntervention(string id)
    {
        return Lookup(id);
    }

    // PATCH tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task<Intervention> PatchIntervention(string id, Delta<Intervention> patch)
    {
        return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }

    // POST tables/TodoItem
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostIntervention(Intervention item)
    {
        Intervention current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }

    // DELETE tables/TodoItem/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
    public Task DeleteIntervention(string id)
    {
        return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
```

The table object
Which matches with the table fields etc.
     public class Intervention : EntityData
    {

```
    //public Guid Id { get; set; }


    public string InterventionGroupId { get; set; }

    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    public string ResultId { get; set; }


    public string OptionText { get; set; }


    public bool SilentTrigger { get; set; }


    public bool Active { get; set; }


    public Nullable<DateTime> DateDeactivated { get; set; }


    public int ProjectId { get; set; }



}
```

The mobile push  logic

```
                    IMobileServiceSyncTable<Intervention> todoTable;
                todoTable = client.GetSyncTable<Intervention>();
                await todoTable.PullAsync("intervention", todoTable.CreateQuery());
```

Mobile table object

```
public class Intervention
{

    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "InterventionGroupId")]
    public string InterventionGroupId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Prefix")]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ResultId")]
    public string ResultId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "OptionText")]
    public string OptionText { get; set; }

    //[Column(Name = "OptionRequired", DbType = "bit  NOT Null", CanBeNull = false)]
    //public bool OptionRequired { get; set; }

    //[Column(Name = "CommentsRequired", DbType = "bit NOT Null", CanBeNull = false)]
    //public bool CommentsRequired { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SilentTrigger")]
    public bool SilentTrigger { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Active")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DateDeactivated")]
    public Nullable<DateTime> DateDeactivated { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProjectId")]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could firstly get the details error  message. I suggest you could use azure remote debug or use config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always; to get the details error message. More details, you could refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010399/how-do-i-return-an-exception-from-azure-mobile-services/35063369).

Comment: Thanks, will look at this and hope this will point me to the problem.